# WMI missing MSMQ queue name

Tags: wmi, msmq

Running the following query in WMI fails to return 2 queues that are active on the computer.

SELECT Name,messagesinqueue FROM Win32_PerfRawdata_MSMQ_MSMQQueue

Anyone know what could be causing this problem. I get plenty of queues listed, but missing 2 important ones that I'd like to monitor in cacti.

Comment: How do you determine that they are active? Do they contain messages or are actively held open by an application?

Comment: They're active because there are messages being sent to and read from the queue.

Comment: OK, that doesn't necessarily mean they are active at the moment when you want to collect data. MSMQ only maintains performance data for queues that it regards as active - ones that contain messages or are actively held open by an application. If you have an application continually listening on a queue for new messages then that would count as active.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by restarting MSMQ. Apparently MSMQ doesn't register queue names with WMI while its running. Needs to be restarted before the new queues will show up.